# Error en $_files['file_import']['tmp_name']

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Cuando envió la información del formulario al servidor me sale el siguiente error Undefined index file_import segun lo que veo en el codigo no se cual pueda ser el error.

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('welcome/importar_datos')?>" method="POST">
    <div class="container">
        Archivo<input type="file" name="file_import" id="file_import">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Importar</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

codigo php

```
public function importar_datos(){
    $file_import = $_POST['file_import'];
    $dir = base_url('static/upload/');
    $file_upload = $dir.basename($file_import);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_import']['tmp_name'], $file_upload)) {
        echo "El fichero es válido y se subió con éxito.\n";
    } else {
        echo "¡Posible ataque de subida de ficheros!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debería utilizar $_FILES en vez de $_POST

ejemplo:

```
$file_import = $_POST['file_import'];
//sustiturlo por
if(isset($_FILES["file_import"]["name"]))
   $file_import=$_FILES["file_import"]["name"];
```

si es codenigter utiliza la siguiente

```
 $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->data('file_import');//devuelve el nombre del archivo
            if (  $this->upload->do_upload('file_import'))
            {
             $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            }
```

Comment: cuando hago var_dump($file_import) me aparece NULL

Comment: revisa que trae $_FILES con var_dump

Comment: var_dump($_FILES)   ...........{ }

Comment: Me parece que te falta el enctype del formulario `enctype="multipart/form-data"` si no lo pones $_FILES va a llegar vacio

Comment: Muchas gracias colegas por la ayuda. La solución de Jakala me sirvió.